# How to make the position of the eye icon responsive

Tags: css

At `@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)` the content gets aligned centered. The eye icon which is positioned absolute gets way off. On large devices it is ok but col-sm-12 and below its position has problem.

The reason why i positioned it absolute is that i want the icon to not move. In the original code there is a functionality to hide and show password  and the icon moved based on the length of the text.

```css
.card-plans {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(217,214,217,1);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(217,214,217,1);
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(217,214,217,1);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
  
  .container-plans {
    padding: 5px 28px 5px 28px !important;
  }

  .cred-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .details {
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }

  .details:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }


.current-plan {
font-size: 18px;
background: yellowgreen;
padding: 3px 15px;
display: inline-block;
}

.e {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.pass {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.stars {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.45ex;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 78px; */
  left: 300px;
}

.card-plans {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

    
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)  {
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.x {
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
} 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="e">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">
                  <div class="card-plans">
                    <div class="container-plans">
                      <br>
                      <p class="cred-title">Credentials</p><br>
                     <div class="center">
                      <p class="details"><strong>Username:</strong>&nbsp;Joha Lee</p>
                      <p class="details"><strong>Password:</strong>&nbsp;
                        <span class="stars">****************************</span>
                        <i class="x fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                       </p>
                        <br>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                     
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                  <div class="card-plans">
                    <div class="container-plans">
                      <br>
                      <p class="cred-title">Current Plan </p><br>
                      <div class="center">               
                      <p class="details"><strong>Type:</strong>&nbsp; Dxx Emails</p>
                      <p class="details"><strong>Plan Cost:</strong>&nbsp; 3332/ Month
                      </p>
                       <br>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When position absolute, make sure you have a good relative.
I placed your eye in the password xxxx field. And made that relative.
No media query is needed then.

```css
.card-plans {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(217,214,217,1);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(217,214,217,1);
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0px rgba(217,214,217,1);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
  
  .container-plans {
    padding: 5px 28px 5px 28px !important;
  }

  .cred-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .relative {
  position: relative
  }

  .details {
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }

  .details:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }


.current-plan {
font-size: 18px;
background: yellowgreen;
padding: 3px 15px;
display: inline-block;
}

.e {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.pass {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.stars {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.45ex;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
}

.card-plans {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

    
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)  {
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.x {
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
} 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="e">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">
                  <div class="card-plans">
                    <div class="container-plans">
                      <br>
                      <p class="cred-title">Credentials</p><br>
                     <div class="center">
                      <p class="details"><strong>Username:</strong>&nbsp;Joha Lee</p>
                      <p class="details"><strong>Password:</strong>&nbsp;
                        <span class="stars relative">****************************<i class="x fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                         
                       </p>
                        <br>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                     
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                  <div class="card-plans">
                    <div class="container-plans">
                      <br>
                      <p class="cred-title">Current Plan </p><br>
                      <div class="center">               
                      <p class="details"><strong>Type:</strong>&nbsp; Dxx Emails</p>
                      <p class="details"><strong>Plan Cost:</strong>&nbsp; 3332/ Month
                      </p>
                       <br>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
</div>
```